# Error on multiple myfunction in onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting an error ReferenceError: options is not defined at myfunctionFDI(OverallScript.gs:39:48)at onEdit(OverallScript.gs:3:1), when I am trying to run multiple myfunctions within onEdit, what am I doing wrong, it appears to run the first myfunction correctly. Help would be appreciated script is here

```
function onEdit(e) {
myfunctionMCR(e);
myfunctionFDI(e);
}
function myfunctionMCR(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "joebloggs@blogs.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cellvalue === 'MCR Approved'){ 
  message = 'Cell ' + cell + ' in Sheet MAN ' + sheetName + ' was changed to MCR Approved and is ready for your Review & Approval.';
  var subject = 'Cell Changed to MCR Approved';
  var body = message + '  Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the change and approve';
  var options = {
  cc: "fredblogs@blogs.com,bobblogs@blogs.com"
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body, options);
  }
 }
 function myfunctionFDI(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "fredblogs@blogs.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cellvalue === 'FDI'){ 
  message = 'Cell ' + cell + ' in Sheet MAN ' + sheetName + ' was changed to FDI and is ready for your review.';
  var subject = 'Cell Changed to FDI Review';
  var body = message + '  Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' FDI to Review';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body, options);
  };
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no value for "Options"  in `function myfunctionFDI(e)`.

- In myfunctionMCR(e), options is defined as follows:

`var options = { cc: "fredblogs@blogs.com,bobblogs@blogs.com" }`

But this variable is only available to myfunctionMCR(e).

- In myfunctionFDI(e), there is no `options` variable. so the code fails.

  - create a variable, along the same lines as in myfunctionMCR(e).